# Extend Firebase SMS Expiration Time

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to extend the Firebase SMS expiration time?  Seems to only be valid about a minute or so and sometimes it takes longer than that to receive the SMS.

Update: I'm sending the SMS through the web API

Comment: Disclaimer: haven't done this - but I found [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) (_section 2_) that includes a timeout parameter, leading me to say "yes" you can customize the timeout. That page also links to [the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/c2f3ae5a111028cdfe86e53f5d59915f8ef0917e/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/java/PhoneAuthActivity.java#L206-L211) which shows that if you use the default method, they coded it for a 60 second timeout - so your "_about a minute_" estimation is spot-on.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention that I'm using the web API, and it looks like the web API `verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, applicationVerifier)` only takes these parameters

Comment: After quite a bit of digging in the source code I haven't been able to find a comparably accessible method in the web sdk - I don't think they offer it here either. Weird how they offer it easily for Android, but not the other SDKs... but maybe I'm blind and it's hidden in there somewhere, but I don't think they do.

Comment: The expiration time is not customizable. However, the SMS expiration should be a lot longer than 1 minute.

Comment: I've email their support and confirmed that the default is 60 seconds for the WEB SDK, at least.  Support also verified that currently, there is no way to get around this for web.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this the latest answer for now, emailed and confirmed with firebase team support, today. Below's their reply:

```
The expiration time related to email links and OTP codes are defined as follows (there is no way to modify them):

Password reset: 1 hour,
Email change notice: 6 hours,
Email verification: 3 days,
Email link sign-in: 6 hours,
OTP code (phone auth): 15 minutes.
```