# How to regenerate a new verification code after resend button click in Firebase Phone Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I was involved in a project that incorporates Phone Authentication. One of the stipulations is that the verification code remains valid for just one minute after its dispatch. Additionally, upon clicking the "Resend" button, a fresh code should be sent, rendering any previous codes obsolete.

At present, the resend functionality functions as intended, except that it generates the prior code if more than 15 minutes have passed.

Is there a method to ensure that the resend function generates a new OTP code rather than the previous one?

Answer (score 2):

As described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545721/extend-firebase-sms-expiration-time) stack thread the expiration time of OTP code is set by the Firebase folks and can't be modified.
15 minutes of expiration time for this code is not a serious security vulnerability since after it's been used once the code is burned and can not be used again.

In fact, setting this time to something really small (like one minute) or generating a new code, and burning the previous one every time the user requests it, could lead to more serious login issues for your users.
SMS authentication has several points of possible failure that could cause delays, or delivery issues. In the scenario you described, your users could easily get stuck in a loop of requesting new code, receiving the previous one and getting annoyed why it's not working.

If your app requires something more secure (and cheaper) then you may look into using MFA with [TOTP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/totp-mfa) as second factor.